# Sharepoint "forgot password" email redirectory

Tags: 2013, email, redirect

My organisation works in a direct sync environment so all our Microsoft products are linked via one account. Whenever a user clicks "forgot password" an email will be sent to the helpdesk and they will help users to restore their password. Only with our SharePoint whenever users click "forgot password" an email is sent to all  the Admins. Is there a way to change this so only the helpdesk will receive this mail?